# Trying to make array in react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I have a problem with making my ButtonGroup dynamic, I tried a lot but nothing seems to work, can someone help me, please?

```
import React from 'react';
import { ButtonGroup } from 'react-native-elements';

export default class WebsiteFilter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            WebsiteFilter: 3
    };
}

updateIndex = ( WebsiteFilter ) => this.setState({ WebsiteFilter })

render() {
    const buttons= ['Vergelijkdirect', 'Ivanhoe', 'Bespaarcoach'];
    let { WebsiteFilter } = this.state;
    return (
        <ButtonGroup
            textStyle={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 12, }}
            onPress={this.updateIndex}
            WebsiteFilter={WebsiteFilter}
            buttons={buttons}
        />
    );
    }
}
```

Instead of:

```
const buttons= ['Vergelijkdirect', 'Ivanhoe', 'Bespaarcoach'];
```

I need to display the domain of this array:

```
[{"id":127,"created_at":"2015-11-02 15:35:11","updated_at":"2016-09-19 11:42:10","deleted_at":null,"customer_id":66,"domain":"http:\/\/vergelijkdirect.com","google_id":"UA-97758230-1","currency_id":1,"root":1,"screenshot":"","integration_date":"2016-09-19 11:42:10"},{"id":283,"created_at":"2017-01-13 16:54:24","updated_at":"2017-01-13 16:54:24","deleted_at":null,"customer_id":66,"domain":"https:\/\/ivanhoe.io","google_id":null,"currency_id":1,"root":0,"screenshot":"","integration_date":null},{"id":327,"created_at":"2017-06-14 19:29:42","updated_at":"2017-06-23 17:29:01","deleted_at":null,"customer_id":66,"domain":"http:\/\/bespaarcoach.vergelijkdirect.com","google_id":"UA-39848260-2","currency_id":1,"root":0,"screenshot":"","integration_date":"2017-06-23 17:29:01"}]
```

Comment: But where does that data come from?

Comment: `const buttons = data.map(o => o.domain);` (react is irrelevant to this question; all you want is to turn an array of objects where each contains a string into an array of those strings).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `buttons` expects an array of strings or components, so in your case, you need to `map` the array and to return the property that you want to display:

```
data.map(e => e.id)
```

Also, the `ButtonGroup` component does not have a property `WebsiteFilter`, it has to be `selectedIndex`.

Your component should look like this:

```
<ButtonGroup
    textStyle={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 12, }}
    onPress={this.updateIndex}
    selectedIndex={this.state.WebsiteFilter}
    buttons={data.map(e => e.id)}
/>
```

Here is a working [demo](https://snack.expo.io/BydNV7m5V).

Comment: Cool, it works. Thank you for helping me out. I really appriciate it :D

Comment: Please check for duplicates before answering very basic questions.